# Prevent color interpolation between pixels within static image in OpenLayers 4

Tags: openlayers

With OpenLayers 4.6.5, I'm creating an Image layer with an ImageStatic source that's in the map's projection and georeferenced.  So, I'm not having a problem with displaying this image on a map background in the projection I've chosen.  I've also turned off image smoothing so the image displays individual pixels when zoomed in via the precompose method (which I discovered in a previous question).  However, upon zooming in, I believe OL is creating  transition colors or intepolating colors between the major color stops in the image.  This is undesirable as the page I'm attempting to build will have a value readout upon mouseover which corresponds to the colors in the image. Displaying the image in image processing software and zooming in does not display this behavior.  Comparing zoomed in images:

From image processor (GIMP)

[image: zoomed image from GIMP]

Zoomed in static image from OL

[image: zoomed in static image from OL]

One can fairly clearly see the difference here where the light purple background pixels are blended with the first green pixels.  But, this seems to be occurring between other pixel colors as well in the OL static image.

While I have an idea on how to prevent this, it would require a bit of work and no guarantee of success.  So I thought I'd ask here first in case I missed a setting or if there's an undocumented configuration setup I could use to prevent this from happening within OL's internal composition canvas.  This did not occur in OL2 but that didn't use the composition canvas either.  This also does not occur for ImageWMS source in OL4.

**EDIT for additional information**

The images I'm displaying are fairly large 2145 x 1377.  Upon looking at a similar display I'm working, just happen to notice that with a smaller image this effect didn't occur when zoomed in.  Conducted some tests on a dataset that is 2345 x 1597 since it had the same issue.  After reducing the image by varying amounts, there's some sort of breakpoint in size reduction where this issue occurs between 10% (still occurs) and 15% (doesn't occur).  Comparison of the two:

At 90 pct of original size

[image]

At 85 pct of original size
[image]

While this might be a work around, I'd still like to know if anything can be done or set so this issue doesn't occur at full image size as reducing the image size could still impact the value readout function during mouseover.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that is a problem of the zoom in in OL. When you zoom in too much openlayers interpolates your pixels but i guess you should report it in it's github issue page.